# Rails Mysql2::Error: Field 'email' doesn't have a default value:

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sorcery

I am using rails 4.2.10 Getting the error while trying to register a user with the Sorcery Gem. I am upgrading the app from rails 3.2

**ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#createActiveRecord**

Mysql2::Error: Field 'email' doesn't have a default value: INSERT 
INTO `users` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2018-03-14 
21:16:53', '2018-03-14 21:16:53')
Extracted source (around line #48):

```
 @user = User.new(user_params)
respond_to do |format|
 ---line 48-----> if @user.save**
    format.html { render action: "thanks", notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
```

userscontroller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:index, :new, :create, :activate]
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all

     respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

     respond_to do |format|
     format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.json
  def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
   def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { render action: "thanks", notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update
   @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
 def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
  def activate
  if (@user = User.load_from_activation_token(params[:id]))
    @user.activate!
    redirect_to(login_path, :notice => 'User was successfully activated.')
 else
    not_authenticated
  end
end
def thanks 
 respond_to do |format|
      format.html # thanks.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end
end
```

========================================================================
Is this the correct migration?

```
    class SorceryCore < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :users do |t|
         t.string :email,            :null => false
         t.string :crypted_password, :null => false
         t.string :salt,             :null => false

         t.timestamps
       end

        add_index :users, :email, unique: true
      end  
   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message given, it seems like there a "NOT NULL" constraint on email field 
and you need to have an email field present with data while inserting.

Solutions to overcome this problem:

1. Check for the migration in db/migrate where email field corresponding to user model is defined.
2. Drop the model/ rollback that specific migration
3. Remove the null(key) constraint from migration file and migrate it again.
4. Check schema.rb and there should be no null: false with the email field.

Comment: added a migration file to the question. Simply take out the :null => false from the description?

Comment: yes..just remove the :null => false from the field which is not mandatory for the insertion of data in the db.